# Как сделать кликер в телеграмм боте?

Tags: python, бот, telebot

я использую python и pyTelegramBotAPI(telebot)
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать кликер в телеграмм боте, что при нажатии кнопки и(или) при вводе сообщения увеличивался счёт пользователя, главное что бы он сохранял результат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, что кликер в телеграмме как-либо реализуем. При каждом клике сервер должен его обрабатывать, а учитывая что пользователь бота будет не один, это колоссальная нагрузка на сервер

Comment: хорошо, а можно сделать как то что бы он фармил автоматически, по типу бота фермы